# In place untar and delete tar (or tar.gz)

Tags: shell, unix, sh, tar, gzip

I have this tiny code here

```
for i in *.tar.gz; 
   do tar xzvf $i;
done && find . -name "*.tar.gz" -exec rm {} \;
```

Now, when I have multiple tars, it will first untar all of them and then delete the tar files.

How can I change the code to untar a file, to delete it and then move to the next tar file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for file in *.tar.gz; do tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}"; done
```

Don't forget to quote your variables to account for funky filenames with whitespace.

Comment: Hi, that seems to do the trick. Thank you a lot. Do yo maybe know a way to check if all the files from the tar were succesfully extracted, and THEN delete the tar?

Comment: @tljubas The `&&` makes sure the right hand side will only be run if the left side returns a zero exit code (terminates successfully), so it should only delete the file if everything went well, on error `rm` won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the order of actions:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do
  tar xzvf "$i" && rm -r "$i"
done
```